# How to show bottom shadow in android

Tags: android

This is my layout file :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/c_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_shadow"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:elevation="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/dp_12"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_1"
                style="@style/Tesco__Theme.Text.H5.DoveGray"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/sw_1"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="4sp"
                android:text="@string/my_text" />
    
            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/sw_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my background file which I am applying on rl1

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/silver" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
         android:bottom="@dimen/dp_2"
       >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/silver" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]

This ai am trying to achieve but i am unable to put bottom shadow using give background XML can any one please help me how to apply bottom shadow with given layout .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're trying to manually apply a bottom shadow. You should just use `android:elevation` as explained here: https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping

Comment: this is not working basically i have to give elevation only in bottom in ConstraintLayout